# How do I trigger a function at the first index of a react-elastic-carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-elastic-carousel

I have a specific request here that is throwing me off. I'm using react-slider-carousel and when it first loads, it has padded about 45px from the left. Then on the next arrow click, it removes the padding (this is done and easy). However, it shouldn't add the padding-left until it reaches its first index. In other words, until there are no more items to the navigate back to. Once it hits the left-most item (index-0) then it adds the padding-left back so that it looks like the way it was initially loaded.

Here's an example functionality that I have right now. It all works except that first index event thing I explained

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Carousel, { consts } from "react-elastic-carousel";
import Item from "./Item";
import "./styles.css";

const breakPoints = [
  { width: 1, itemsToShow: 1 },
  { width: 550, itemsToShow: 2, itemsToScroll: 2 },
  { width: 768, itemsToShow: 3 },
  { width: 1200, itemsToShow: 4 }
];

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function App() {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFirst(true);
  }, []);

  const addPadding = () => {
    setFirst(true);
  };
  const removePadding = () => {
    setFirst(false);
  };

  const renderArrows = ({ type, onClick, isEdge }) => {
    const pointer =
      type === consts.PREV ? (
        <div
          style={{
            top: 5,
            left: 0,
            display: "flex",
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
          onClick={addPadding}
        >
          <span role="img" aria-label="">
            
          </span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          style={{
            top: 5,
            right: 0,
            display: "flex",
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
          onClick={removePadding}
        >
          <span role="img" aria-label="">
            
          </span>
        </div>
      );

    return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        disabled={isEdge}
        style={{
          zIndex: 1010,
          width: 55,
          fill: "black",
          cursor: "pointer",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          transition: "all .8s ease-in-out !default"
        }}
      >
        {pointer}
      </button>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="controls-wrapper">
        <button onClick={removePadding}>Remove Padding</button>
        <button onClick={addPadding}>Add Padding</button>
      </div>
      <hr className="seperator" />
      <div className="carousel-wrapper" style={{ backgroundColor: "maroon" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            paddingLeft: first ? 45 : 15,
            paddingTop: 15,
            paddingBottom: 15,
            paddingRight: 15
          }}
        >
          <Carousel
            breakPoints={breakPoints}
            renderArrow={renderArrows}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
          >
            {items.map((item) => (
              <Item key={item}>{item}</Item>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**[Here's a handy dandy code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-elastic-carousel-forked-keqqtc?file=/src/index.js)** if you need to play around with it. And thanks in advance guys

Comment: It's still not very clear to what is the expected behavior should be or what's wrong with the current one. Is the issue when you reached slide #8 and hit back you get unwanted extra padding-left?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained it in detail, maybe I over explained it. So, the slider loads with a padding on the left side of it (this is done). When you click the right arrow the padding is removed and you notice the slider occupying the entire width of the container/screen (this is also done), and when you click the left arrow (prev arrow), it should NOT add the padding UNLESS there are no more items. Basically, IF you are the second slide, when you click that last available click, it brings up slide 1, but ALSO adds the padding back, thus returning it to the initial load state

Comment: thanks for the details, I've posted one potential solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to utilize [react-elastic-carousel props](https://sag1v.github.io/react-elastic-carousel/#props), such as `onNextStart` and `onPrevStart` which could provide to previous or future items, based on that you could remove/add padding.

Solution:

1. remove `click` assignment on `line:39` and `line:56` for prev/next arrow `div` elements
2. add `onNextStart` and `onPrevStart` callbacks as props on `<Carousel>`
3. include some logic in each `onNextStart` and `onPrevStart` callback to check for `index` for the future item in order to drive logic for padding (add/remove padding).

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-elastic-carousel-forked-lh65jw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Hate to bother you with one more detail. But that's ok if you dont want to answer it since I didn't specify in my OP....How can I make this affect this Carousel only and not other Carousels? In my page I have about 8 of them.

Comment: Let's say you wrap all that logic into component called `MyCustomCarousel` (in example above it's called `App`)
then you can introduce some prop let's call it `hasDynamicPadding`, based on that prop you could do some logic adjustments in for your `onNextStart` and  `onPrevStart` callbacks, then component usage will be 
`<MyCustomCarousel hasDynamicPadding>`
and 
`<MyCustomCarousel>`
and so on

Comment: Yeah I understand the props  part. The logic adjustments is what I can't figure out. I can't find a unique identifier for each slider that I can target to make it work independently. I have a separate question for it here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954568/how-can-i-single-out-which-item-in-my-map-function-should-be-affected-by-my-func`