# How can I single out which item in my map function should be affected by my function call in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of sliders in a page and I have a specific requirement that requires to add a padding to the slider when there are no items below its 0 index. I have this done already, but I can't figure out how to make this function affect only the slider that I am clicking in. Right now, it affects all the sliders in my map function.

I am using react-elastic-carousel and I am targeting specified props, so the functions look like this

```
const onPrevStart = (prevItemObject, nextItemObject) => {
  if (nextItemObject?.index === 0) {
    setFirst(true);
  }
};

const onNextStart = (prevItemObject, nextItemObject) => {
  if (nextItemObject?.index !== 0) {
    setFirst(false);
  }
};
```

then I am calling it in a my map function in the JSX like this

```
<div className="App">

  {items.map((item, index) => (
    <div 
      key={index} 
      className="carousel-wrapper" 
      style={{ backgroundColor: "maroon" }}>
      <div>
        <Carousel
          breakPoints={breakPoints}
          renderArrow={renderArrows} //see the codesandbox to see these
          onPrevStart={onPrevStart} //here
          onNextStart={onNextStart} //and here
          style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>

          {item.itemdata.map((slide, index) => (
            <Item key={index}>{slide}</Item>
          ))}

        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

If you look in my [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-elastic-carousel-forked-keqqtc?file=/src/index.js) that I've made for you to play around with, you can test the functionality and see what I mean.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: `const [first, setFirst] = useState(true);` creates a *single* boolean state variable. To handle multiple sliders independently you need an *array of bools*.

Comment: `const [first, setFirst] = useState([ true, true, true....true]); ` <-- this. I'm confused

Comment: What are you confused about? Updating a state array?

Comment: Ok Chris. Thanks for your help in this site for helping people

Comment: Not sure if you're being sarcastic here; I try to help but precise communication is extremely important when it comes to technical issues; I already have full days of people telling me their PC won't start when it turns out that the actual problem is their network connection, so I tend to have a short fuse when people make me worm the details out of them

Comment: Then maybe SO is not the place for you man. This is where we come when we don't have no one in the building to help us out or when we are out of options. The days I have a short fuse and I'm not in the mood to help, I go do something completely unrelated. (Judo, Jiu Jitsu, or guitar do it for me). The last thing I do is more of the same that I am frustrated with. Sorry if my question seemed too obvious for you. It wasn't for me. There are levels of skills and knowledge. And everyone starts with these simple problems.

Comment: This isn't about being a beginner. Not at all. It's about explaining what the issue is instead of saying "I'm confused"

Comment: I thought I explained enough in my OP. I was confused with your vague answer. I think you meant to say "It's about explaining the answer instead of being vague with a comment. A vague answer does confuse a beginner. Do you remember those days?

Comment: I'm sorry if my first comment sounded arrogant but pointing out that a single on/off switch cannot handle multiple lights independently is bound to make the other person feel stupid and I don't have time to tip toe around that possibility each time I post a short comment intended primarily to *help* the other person.

Comment: Chris, I understand. But a single comment doesn't answer the question in a way I need to understand. It requires an answer with an explanation. If you were teaching in a classroom, you wouldn't be this vague. You would explain in detail what is going on and how to solve it properly, like Andrew did in the answer. And this website is technically a virtual classroom for specific problems. Some people use it to get free help and code, but I don't. I never ask a question unless I've done my fair share of trial/error and googling

Comment: I'm not going to go on with this. The question has been answered. So it's moot now. I'm just advising you for the next people that will ask questions. Unless you are prepared to answer with a viable answer and teach them something, it's better that you ignore it and let someone else do it. No point on making a "duh-type" comment as if the solution was evident to everyone. It isn't to them

Comment: This isn't a classroom. My comment is enough to point to googling "react state array" which leads to a lot of existing answers, here and elsewhere. I know it can be hard to find the right search terms if you don't understand what the exact issue is, but this website is not where you are entitled to free beginner's tutoring. It's a last resort (feel free to check the two links in my profile)

Comment: ok Chris. Whatever you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say in order to control each slider individually, you need to break up your `App` component into smaller peaces.

My suggestion is to extract all custom logic for your slider to separate component, let's call it `CustomSliderComponent` and pass some data peaces from `App` to that child component. For example we can pass `data`, some other params like `breakPoints` as well as flags `hasDynamicPadding`.

Using those params we can have more tailored `CustomSliderComponent`  component logic for your needs and then parent `App` component will only orchestrate and render each slider instance individually, where state is not shared but incapsulated inside each custom slider.

[Codesandox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-elastic-carousel-forked-tm6g5x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Outstanding Andrew!!! That really helped me a lot bud. Thanks a million. I owe you a beer!

Comment: You are very welcome, next time when I would visit the capital of Commonwealth :)